# "you can" or "you could" or "you may" or "you might"?

Tags: word-choice, auxiliary-verbs

When someone say:

- You can do something.
- You could do something.
- You may do something.
- You might do something.

It sounds like each of them can be expressing possibility or suggestion.
I know there must be some differences between them. But what the differences exactly are?

Thank you!

Comment: A dictionary search should have given you most of this.

Comment: ... or a search on this site.

Comment: @JohnFeltz A dictionary will not be of much help to a learner in the elementary stages when it comes to conditionals, especially if the OP's first language is heavily inflected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short and simple answer is that they are varying degrees of uncertainty.

If you say *The cat is dead* you are 100% sure the cat is dead, otherwise you wouldn't say it. If you say *the cat might/may/could be* dead you are not 100% certain. If you say *the cat can be dead* it is a possibility, but you don't know if it actually true or not. If you say *the cat must be dead* then you are voicing a conclusion, but again you don't know if it true or not.

Viewing modality as a matter formality is simplistic. More formality usually correlates to less directness, and less directness manifests in speech as more uncertainty expressed through modal verbs, but this is a side-effect of a behaviour issue more than a linguistic one.

Comment: "He can be alive" (let's be more positive about life) sounds awkward. The toss up is between *could* and *might*, with *may* coming in third position. With possibility, I often use parking as a scenario: *I can/could/may/might park here* are all acceptable, but convey subtle differences in meanings.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience:

- "You can" tends to mean that someone is *able to* do something that they probably thought they wouldn't be able to.
  / ability / permission / certainty / possibility
- "You could" means that although it is technically possible to do something, you aren't likely to.
  Formal suggestion / formal possibility / past ability
- "You may" is similar to "You can," but is more formal.
  / permission / formal suggestion / weak degree of certainty
- "You might" implies that the question was not if it was possible or not, but rather if they *would*. Also, it often means that it is most likely that you will not do the action but that it is a possibility. / suggestion / weak degree of certainty / formal suggestion

Although these differences are small, they *may* ;) help you seem more like a native speaker. Still, these differences are small and you can often use any of the words.